# Move data from Amazon S3 to Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can we connect Amazon S3 buckets present in two different regions and migrate CSV Files data into one Particular region Amazon RDS ? I am trying to use AWS Glue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly different ways to solve this use case. You can use AWS Glue. You can also write a workflow using AWS Step Functions that can solve this as well. For example, you can write a series of Lambda functions that can read CSV in an Amazon S3 bucket, get the values and then write the values to an Amazon RDS database. Both ways are valid.

See these docs as ref:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/orchestrate-multiple-etl-jobs-using-aws-step-functions-and-aws-lambda/

https://aws.amazon.com/glue/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc

Keep in mind however. a workflow is not ideal when your data set is so large, it will timeout the 15 min window that Lambda uses. In this case, you should use AWS Glue.